# eclipse tomcate configuration

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, configuration

How to rum my jsp page in eclipse galileo?

I got only 2 options that is run as applet and second is run as application.. and both are invalid what to do? What problem should there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using `Eclipse IDE for Java developers`, which does not have WTP (web application) support.  You should use `Eclipse for Java EE developers` or install the WTP related plugins.